# Wall on FaceBook

Tags: delphi, facebook

i would like to post a message on facebook wall (standard friend/group's wall) not the Apps. using delphi, i could log-in but i dont know how to post a message on it. any suggestion?

Comment: Please, clarify if you want to post a message from a Facebook Application (using facebook api) or if you want to log in using an standard account and publish on a friend/group's wall?

Comment: @jachguate, yes if it posible to post on my friends Wall not using the facebook api. is it posible?

Answer (score 3):

[`delphibook`](http://code.google.com/p/delphibook/) is a Delphi library to support Facebook applications.

Answer (score 3):

I have never used Delphi so im not sure about the language structure

but facebook API is basically HTTP Requests, you should be able to build a class that upon instanation you would authorize your app and then have a set of methods that publish data via HTTPRequest and validate the response

Heres something you may wish to look at:

Facebook emailer in delphi via CakeMail: http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=17522112271

And how to post via HTTP:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post

Answer (score 3):

It is possible.

If you're able to login you can use a sniffer to take a look for the details of how it is accomplished by Facebook itself when you do it withing a browser (kind of reverse engineering).  [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is the best tool for me.

Look and take your time to understand what's going on between your browser and the servers when you post messages to your friend's wall.

Once you understand the details, you can mimic the exact same behavior from your Delphi program to get the same results, for example with the TidHTTP or TidTCP components.

Facebook is AJAX intensive: series of HTTP GET/POST operations without full page refreshes.

Don't forget you're mimicking a undocumented and internal communication mechanism.  Facebook or any other target site may change it's internal's and broke your program compatibility anytime.

Remember this kind of program may be prohibited... read the facebook agreement's for further details.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible links that may provide some guidance? They are not in delphi, but I assume the api would be similar to javascript/php ?

http://daipratt.co.uk/using-fb-api-to-make-a-full-post-to-a-users-wall/

http://blog.theunical.com/facebook-integration/5-steps-to-publish-on-a-facebook-wall-using-php/